# How to disable auto menu in Gnome after login?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

For a few weeks, GNOME has always been showing the "application menu" as if I pressed the Windows / Super key after login using GDM and I have to press the Super key again to hide it every time. Is that an intended change and how can I disable that?

I'm using GNOME Shell 40.2 at the moment but I don't know, in which version that changed exactly.

Comment: Yes, it's an intentional change in GNOME 40. The reasoning (IIRC) is that (a) most people start some application as the first thing to do and (b) the overview is where those applications are shown, so the obvious thing to do is show the overview when people login instead of a (blank by default) desktop . See the section on "Boot experience" in https://blogs.gnome.org/shell-dev/2021/01/07/a-shell-ux-update/

Comment: @muru: I don't find that obvious because my frequently used applications are on hotkeys and for the rest I mostly use the terminal so I rarely use the overview but I can understand why it is better for new users without hotkeys, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Gnome extension that should automatically hide the application menu after login.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4099/no-overview/

Give it a try.